# MYSQL No suitable driver found

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I currently use Intellij, it turns out that I am trying to connect to a MySQL database, but after adding the library and using a connection class which works perfectly with the MariaDB driver, I find the error in the question title

```
public void conectar() {
        try {
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contraseña);
            if (conexion != null) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión establecida a : \n" + url,  "ACDA2", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                stm = conexion.createStatement();//crea un objeto que permite enviar instrucciones a la base de datos
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión fallida a : \n " + url, "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cargar el driver", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

These are the values ​​that I send to my class connection

`c= new conexion("jdbc:mysql://", "127.0.0.1/", "root", "", "sanciones");
     c.conectar();`

And then I detail the connection class constructor

```
 public conexion(String driver,String host, String usuario, String 
 contraseña, String baseDatos) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
    this.baseDatos = baseDatos;
    this.driver = driver;
    this.host = host;
    this.url = driver + this.host  + this.baseDatos;
}
```

UPDATE

The driver versions com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5 do not allow the implicit loading of the driver due to the lack of the Services subfolder in META-INF and its corresponding content, even if it is JDBC4 and in the mysql manuals it is said that it is possible, it is not, at least with this specific version, greetings

Comment: My guess is that the MySQL/MariaDB driver JAR is not on your classpath, and is therefore not available at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName should be called before getting connection

Comment: This works!!! but I have a great doubt, I read that class for name is not necessary for the operation of the library, why would it be necessary to place it in this case?

Comment: Because to get the connection you need to load the driver first.

Comment: but if I use the mariadb driver, it works for me by loading it later: /

Answer (score 0):

"Class.forName" need to be called first to load the proper driver first.Try this,

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contraseña);
        if (conexion != null) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión establecida a : \n" + url,  "ACDA2", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            stm = conexion.createStatement();//crea un objeto que permite enviar instrucciones a la base de datos
        }
```

Comment: Oh nice its work, you know why with mariadb driver I can called Class.forName after?